# CSS Inspecting Line-height in browsers

Tags: css

I was trying to figure out is there any way to inspect individual line element in the browser. Right now right clicking the line of text visualizes whole paragraph but I am trying to visualize each line (specifically) I want to see how much height is each line taking so is there any way to do this.

Comment: adding css line-height:XXpx; (move the arrows up/down) and see when it changes is no option?

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the `line-height:` property of text on a page?  I think you should look into a firefox extension [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a border to an inline element:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/3ruzzpix

```
<p><span>...</span></p>

span {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Very simple and effective :) I didn't think of that. However still any way to do it via browser inspect or some other addon any way on a side note :D

Comment: This does not show the line-height. It just adds border around each word. Do `p {line-height: 1.6em;}` for instance to see the difference.

Comment: I last downvoted 5 mins ago and I can't take it back, but add "display: inline-block;" and it will work.

Comment: This is wrong because it won't work all the time. For example, when there is padding `padding: 10px`

Answer (score 1):

If you install a Chrome Extension ([**Snazzy Snippet**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil)) it adds an option to the Developer Tools and captures all the CSS properties applying to a selected element even if they aren't immediately visible. Might be worth a look.

Comment: Still not sure whether it will get height of lines or not :D